# I converted gets to fgets but the code enters an infinite loop

Tags: c, fgets

```
 int count_line=0;
       char note[500];
           // printf("enter line %d: ",count_line);
           while( fgets(note,500,stdin)){

             if (strcmp(note,"END")==0){
               // printf("not almayi bitirdi\n");
                break;
            }
            entry[count_entry].notes = (char **) realloc(entry[count_entry].notes, (count_line+1)*sizeof(char *)); // yeni satir gelebilir diye yer actim
            entry[count_entry].notes[count_line] = (char *) malloc(500*sizeof(char)); // yeni actigim satirda 500 karakterlik yer actim
            strcpy(entry[count_entry].notes[count_line],note);  // 0
            entry[count_entry].numberOfLines ++; // 1
                count_line++;
           }

       count_entry++;
    }
```

The compiler does not support `gets` that's why I used `fgets` but now there is infinite loop when I entered `END` it does not break the loop.

How to fix this?

Comment: BTW, there is no need to cast memory allocation functions in C. If you compiler complains, its probably a C++ compiler.

Comment: code runs perfectly with gets() in code blocks, but when I upload it to the school system, it prints warning as you should not use gets() function. That's why I had do change it

Comment: With this "*memory allocation functions*" I tried to refer to `malloc()`, `calloc()` and `realloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets()` returns the new-line, if input had been ended by pressing enter.

So the code either needs to chop off the new-line

```
    note[strcspn(note, "\n")] = '\0';
```

or test for `"END\n"`.

Comment: When I add \n to END command it exits the whole program. But this is just inner loop. so END command only need to exit the these while loop

Comment: also  note[strcspn(note, "\n")] = '\0';  where should I this ? After which line?

Comment: "*it exits the whole program*": I cannot comment on this, as the relevant code is not shown. Any ways you asked why the loop is not left, now you know why.

Comment: "*After which line?*" think twice: There only is a new-line around to be chopped off when reading is done. This is *after* the call to `fgets()`. Also I explained the new-line makes the comparison fail. So then chop off the new-line before you compare, that is *before* calling `strcmp()`.